# Telerik Grid Client template data not saved while Submit button press

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I am using telerik controls in my project when i am using client template for a column  but the data appears in client template not saving while submit button press, it is showing empty template. Below is my code

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<edairy.Models.ReceiptsEntry.mst_stock_dtl>()
    .Name("gdStkDetails")
            .ToolBar(commands =>{ commands.Insert();
               commands.SubmitChanges();
            } )


           .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Trans_No))
             .Pageable(paging =>
                    paging.PageSize(10)
                          .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                          .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                          .Sortable(sorting => sorting
                          .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                                  .ClientEvents(e => e.OnDataBound("onDataBound"))

                          .DataBinding(databing => databing.Ajax()
                                                           .Select("SelectStock", "ReceiptsEntry")
                                                           //.Insert("AddStock", "ReceiptsEntry")
                                                           .Update("Editproduct", "ReceiptsEntry")
                                                           //.Delete("DeleteStock", "ReceiptsEntry")
                                                           )


           .Columns(columns =>
            {
               columns.Bound(c => c.Trans_No).Title("Transaction No").Width(100);
               columns.Bound(c => c.Product_cd).Title("Product Code").EditorTemplateName("GrdDropdown").Width(150);
               columns.Bound(c => c.Prouduc_desc).Title("Product Desc").EditorTemplateName("text").Width(100);
               columns.Bound(c => c.Prouduc_desc).Title("Product Desc").ClientTemplate("<input type='text' id='text' name='ProductDesc' /> ").Width(100);
               columns.Bound(c => c.Receipt_Quantity).Title("Receipt Qty").Width(150);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
           // commands.Edit();
            commands.Delete();
              });
            })

            .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            //.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))

                )

                </text>);
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Render();
}
```

kindly help me in this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Trying change your action to something like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [GridAction]
public ActionResult Editproduct([Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<edairy.Models.ReceiptsEntry.mst_stock_dtl> data)
```

Be, carefully when you change the data on the grid you need to be sure the focus leave the textbox, because the grid needs to know the value on the textbox was changed.. try it.

hope this, help.